# Uniswap's swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens gives "transfer amount exceeds allowance" error

Tags: erc-20, uniswap, swaps, erc-20-approve

I am experimenting with Uniswap's `swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens`  method by attempting to swap `USDC -> WETH -> UNI-v2` using `ethers.js` just for the sake of understanding how the function works.
My transaction fails with error `TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED` that in my experience is almost always caused by not calling the `approve` method before the swap. Surely enough, when I check the parity trace on Goerli's etherscan.io I see that the error returned from the last call in my transaction is `(ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance)`. My question is, which contract must I approve here? Approving Uniswap's v2 router did not work.

Here is such a failed transaction: https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x677fef980f6e7ee813282811cb2edcf8bc71ceb6f61a9969574506084e89b112

Comment: Yes, the allowance must be the issue. Looking at your Tx history, looks like you have succeed approving and swapping now?

Comment: Indeed I have, I will write the answer shortly

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was approving UniswapV3's contract to spend balance of the token in question but `swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens` method was called on Uniswap's V2 router contract. Once I gave V2 Router contract the approval to spend, the transaction worked fine.